# Python script - extract from MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server-2008

We have a pbx running SQL server. I need help writing a python script to extract some calls from the db by range of time (all incoming calls within last 60 mins). How do i get this info using datetime function?

Comment: Hi, I think your question is too broad to get a good answer. can you post the current state of your script and the structure of the tables you want to use ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
begin = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(minutes=60)
cur.execute('''SELECT dtcol 
               FROM your_table 
               WHERE dtcol >= %s''',(begin,))
row = cur.fetchone() # get first row of resultset
```